# 64 bit versus 32 bit for Windows phone development

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I just spent all day loading up my new windows 8 laptop with all my dev tools.  Only to find out that my OS version was the 32 bit version.

When I tried to run the emulator for my windows phone 8 app I got an error saying I needed "Hyper-V".  Apparently "Hyper-V" is only available on the 64 bit version.

I have a two part question.  How do I develop using my current 32 bit OS and dev tools?  From what I'm reading I can still test with a registered phone.  Any information on how to do this?

The other question is, do I bite the bullet now and upgrade to the 64 bit OS (which is a reformat and re-installation of everything)?

Thanks

Comment: Ouch. I'm not sure of the answer but I'd settle for a bit of time upfront and get the environment right rather than have potentially constant battles down the road

Comment: Some sources indicate that you can run Virtual PC 2007 SP1 in Windows 8, as long as you select Compatibility Mode.  System requirements for Virtual PC are much less stringent than for Win 8 Hyper-V.

Comment: I disagree with this being closed as I found the answers received to be VERY helpful!  Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would bite the bullet and upgrade to 64 bit now.  The full system requirements for Windows Phone 8 development are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471).  Besides needing 64-bit Windows 8 Pro or higher to use the Windows Phone 8 emulator, the other "gotcha" is needing a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).

PCs that support SLAT are Intel-based processors that start with i (e.g., i3, i5, i7, i9) or any CPUs based on the Nehalem, Westmere, or Sandybridge micro-architectures.

To determine if your machine supports SLAT, perform the following steps:

1. Download SysInternals/TechNet CoreInfo at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722
2. Run "coreinfo -v"
3. If you have "*" next to "EPT", you should be good.  If you have a "-" next to EPT, your processor doesn't support SLAT.

Comment: Darn...  That is what I ultimately want to do, but I don't want to do it either (if that makes any sense).  Thanks for the info.  I have an i7 so I should be OK.

Comment: Totally makes sense!  I've been in that situation too.  :)  Good luck.

Comment: I just checked and I do have the "*" next to the "EPT" so I guess I good to go with upgrading it.

Answer (score 1):

If you hace a Windows Phone 8 device you can "unlock" it and deploy and debug apps in it, so you can keep your 32 bits OS.

Otherwise, you need to format and install a 64 bits version of Windows 8.

Comment: yeah I read that.  I do have a WP8 device.  Can you envision any future issues I might have with staying with the 32bit OS?

Comment: Not if you hace a WP8 device. But if you're going to get into W8 development too, I'd upgrade in order to test 32 and 64 bits versions of the application (even if you weren't going too I'd upgrade too, actually).